# Change the telephone field from 'Telephone' to only 'Mobile Number' at Checkout

Tags: checkout

I want to change the telephone field from 'Telephone' to only 'Mobile Number' when a customer fills in their details

Comment: Please mention magento version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use locale files to change any labels.

Find the following files:

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Persistent.csv
```

Where `en_US` is your current locale.

Find the following line `"Telephone","Telephone"` and change the second part to your `"Telephone","Mobile Number"`.

If it is not working find all `"Telephone","Telephone"` under folder `app/locale/en_US/` and change the second value.